# Linq to MySQL exception: Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list' exception

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am using some group operation for Linq to MySQL expression, but ToList operation call an error *Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'*:

```
var partnersStats = (from u in ObjectContext.Member.Where(o => o.RegisterTime >= startDateTime && o.RegisterTime <= endDateTime)
                                 group u by new { u.PartnerId, u.RegisterTime.Year, u.RegisterTime.Month, u.RegisterTime.Day, u.partners.Name } 
                                 into pgroup
                                 let count = pgroup.Count()
                                 select new PartnersUsersInfo
                                 {
                                     PartnerId = pgroup.Key.PartnerId,
                                     PartnerName = pgroup.Key.Name,
                                     PartnerUsersAmount = count,
                                     Year = pgroup.Key.Year,
                                     Month = pgroup.Key.Month,
                                     Day = pgroup.Key.Day
                                 }).ToList();
```

I am using  latest version of MySql connector. If I write AsEnumerable query is working but any way after some extra operations it call the same error.
How to fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure that AsEnumerable works? It probably just defers the code execution? I would suggest running a SQL trace to get the actual SQL..that is probably where the problem is coming from

Comment: try group by `u.RegisterTime` instead of three columns `u.RegisterTime.Year, u.RegisterTime.Month, u.RegisterTime.Day`

Comment: to Grundy I need to group by date only, this column contain time as well

Comment: Must be a bug, sorry. Sql Connector tripping over its aliases.

Comment: Indeed, appears to be a MySQL LINQ bug that I am still seeing in 6.8.3 as documented here: http://jhonjairoroa87.blogspot.com/2013/09/net-unknown-column-groupby1k1-in-field.html -- I opted regrettably to not use LINQ for this.